# download CSV from flask sqlalchemy

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a route page called `/showall` which display all few rows from the sqlite3 DB along with a button called "download CSV", if you want to download them all.

my `display.html` looks like below:

```
<a href="/download/{{ value }}" target="blank"><button>Download CSV
                        <i class="zmdi zmdi-arrow-right"></i>
                    </button></a>
```

my `app.py` looks like below:

```
@app.route('/showall', methods=["GET"])
def showall():
    title = "Display"
    data = database.get_all(Registers)
    with open('/tmp/download.csv', 'w') as f:
        out = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        header = Registers.__table__.columns.keys()
        out.writerow(header)

        for rec in data:
            out.writerow([getattr(rec, c) for c in header])

    return render_template("display.html", title=title, data=data, value='download.csv')


@app.route('/download/<file_name>')
def download(file_name):
    try:
        return send_file("/tmp/" + file_name,
                         attachment_filename='all_register.csv',
                         as_attachment=True)
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)
```

as soon as my `/showall` page is up and I hover around the "download" button I could see the redirect link as `/download/download.csv` but as soon as I click the button nothing happens.

But strange thing if I go to page source of `showall` and click the link from the page source, then it downloads the csv.
How can I fix this and what I'm missing from the page?

Comment: Why does the download button point to `/download/download.html` when you hover over it? Shouldn't it point to `/download/download.csv`? Also, the link's target should be `target="_blank"`

Comment: my bad...it points to `download.csv`, not the `download.html`. I have updated the question. Also, `_blank` has no effect.

Comment: Does the browser send a GET request when you click the download link? Can you check in your browser's DevTools?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="/showall" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="get">
<a href="/download/{{ value }}" target="blank"><button>Download CSV
                        <i class="zmdi zmdi-arrow-right"></i>
                    </button></a>
</form>
```